# How To Get The Unique Name Count With PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say I have text file Data.txt with:

```
26||jim||1990
31||Tanya||1942
19||Bruce||1612
8||Jim||1994
12||Brian||1988
56||Susan||2201
```

and it keeps going.

It has many different names in column 2.
Please tell me, how do I get the count of unique names, and how many times each name appears in the file using PHP?

I have tried:

```
$counts = array_count_values($item[1]);
echo $counts;
```

after exploding ||, but it does not work.
The result should be like:
jim-2, 
tanya-1, 
and so on.
Thanks for any help...

Comment: Show the code you've attempted so far, and we'll try to help fix it. But you do have to show SOME effort - we won't write it for you. That's not how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on this:

1. Use [`file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read the data file, producing an array where each element corresponds to a line in the input.
2. Use [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with [`trim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) as the filter function to remove blank lines from this array. This takes advantage that `trim` returns a string having removed whitespace from both ends of its argument, leaving the empty string if the argument was all whitespace to begin with. [The empty string converts to boolean `false`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) -- thus making `array_filter` disregard lines that are all whitespace.
3. Use [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with a callback that involves calling `explode` to split each array element (line of text) into three parts and returning the second of these. This will produce an array where each element is just a name.
4. Use `array_map` again with [`strtoupper`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) as the callback to convert all names to uppercase so that "jim" and "JIM" will count as the same in the next step.
5. Finally, use [`array_count_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get the count of occurrences for each name.

Code, taking things slowly:

```
function extract_name($line) {
    // The -1 parameter (available as of PHP 5.1.0) makes explode return all elements 
    // but the last one. We want to do this so that the element we are interested in
    // (the second) is actually the last in the returned array, enabling us to pull it
    // out with end(). This might seem strange here, but see below.
    $parts = explode('||', $line, -1);
    return end($parts);
}

$lines = file('data.txt'); // #1
$lines = array_filter($lines, 'trim'); // #2
$names = array_map('extract_name', $lines); // #3
$names = array_map('strtoupper', $names); // #4
$counts = array_count_values($names); // #5

print_r($counts); // to see the results
```

There is a reason I chose to do this in steps where each steps involves a function call on the result of the previous step -- that it's actually possible to do it in just one line:

```
$counts = array_count_values(
          array_map(function($line){return strtoupper(end(explode('||', $line, -1)));},
          array_filter(file('data.txt'), 'trim')));

print_r($counts);
```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yptXOW)**.

I should mention that this might not be the "best" way to solve the problem in the sense that if your input file is *huge* (in the ballpark of a few million lines) this approach will consume a lot of memory because it's reading all the input in memory at once. However, it's certainly convenient and unless you know that the input is going to be that large there's no point in making life harder.

*Note: Senior-level PHP developers might have noticed that I 'm violating strict standards here by feeding the result of `explode` to a function that accepts its argument by reference. That's valid criticism, but in my defense I am trying to keep the code as short as possible. In production it would be indeed better to use `$a = explode(...); return $a[1];` although there will be no difference as regards the result.*

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to not only answer me and give examples, but for actually teaching me something. Much appreciated. Let me give it a try and get back here to you...

Answer (score 2):

Read in each line, `explode` using the delimiter (in this case ||), and add it to an array if it does not already exist. If it does, increment the count.

I won't write the code for you, but here a few pointers:

[fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) reads in a line

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will split the line based on a delimiter

use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the name has been found before, and to determine whether you need to add the name to the array or just increment the count.

**Edit:**

Following Jon's advice, you can make it even easier for you.

Read in line-by-line, explode by delimiter and dump all the names into an array (don't worry about checking if it already exists). After you're done, use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get every unique name and its frequency.

Comment: Actually, if you "somehow" project into an array of names there's also [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) available.

Comment: @Jon: Nice! That pretty much solves it for him. PHP was some amazingly useful in built  functions

Comment: Yup, there are enough functions to write this as an one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

While I do feel that this website's purpose is to answer questions and not do homework assignments, I don't acknowledge the assumption that you are doing your homework, since that fact has not been provided. I personally learned how to program by example. We all learn our own ways, so here is what I would do if I were to attempt to answer your question as accurately as possible, based on the information you have provided.

```
<?php
$unique_name_count = 0;
$names = array();

$filename = 'Data.txt';
$pointer = fopen($filename,'r');
$contents = fread($pointer,filesize($filename));
fclose($pointer);

$lines = explode("\n",$contents);

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $split_str = explode('|',$line);
    if(isset($split_str[2]))
    {
        $name = strtolower($split_str[2]);
        if(!in_array($name,$names))
        {
            $names[] = $name;
            $unique_name_count++;
        }
    }
}

echo $unique_name_count.' unique name'.(count($unique_name_count) == 1 ? '' : 's').' found in '.$filename."\n";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. And for the record, it is not homework. I will try this and get back to you here. Thanks again!

Comment: Why the `fopen` ritual when there's [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) available? And why read the contents then explode on newline when there's [`file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)?

Comment: @Jon: while file_get_contents is nice, personally I feel that it's vitally important to introduce [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen), [`fread`](http://php.net/fread), and [`fclose`](http://php.net/fclose) since they are widely used amongst other programming languages. (also note the `$pointer` variable ;-))

Comment: *Vitally* important? I can't remember how many years it's been since `fread` was last called for. And as for "widely used", you probably mean "C" because all other languages I know of can do better than that.

Comment: I have run the code and fixed an error. `$str` was undefined, when I meant to use `$line` from the foreach. My apologies.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that too. However, this code just give the total number of names on the list. I need the number of occurrences of each unique name. Can you still help?

Comment: That depends on how you define 'unique name'. Right off the top of my head, I'm thinking that the best approach to determining the uniqueness of a name is by using [`strtolower`](http://php.net/strtolower), then [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) to check if the name is already in the array. But again, that entirely depends on how you define 'unique name', because while the names "jim" and "Jim" are spelled differently, they are unique in their case sensitivity.

Comment: That is right, but I would like to ignore if the name is capitalized, and count them both as Jim.

Comment: I've applied the changes; test the code out, let me know if you have further issues.

Comment: Thank you for your patients. I believe it is almost there. The result should be a list of unique names and the number of times it occurs. Like: jim - 2, tanya - 1, and so on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6750/discussion-between-zzatkin-and-mobilestimulus)